# In my web site I changed a javascript file but if I view the source of the page there is still the old file

Tags: javascript, html

I modified the javascript file and updated it in my server via FTP.

The problem is that even if i deleted from my browser all the cache I still see the old file.js!

Both javascript file have the same file name. I think if i change the name it will work but I don't want to change the name...

How to fix this?

Comment: sounds like web server may be caching the content?  Have you tried restarting web server.

Comment: Have you verified that the file did in fact overwrite the server side copy?  Download it and check it has the changes.

Comment: yes if i put in the browser the FTP address of the file it's changed. How to restart the webserver? My web site is hosted by altervista.

Comment: What webserver do you use?

Comment: Have you tried requesting the file/page in a 2nd browser? Or clearing your browser's cache / temporary internet files? Some browser versions can be adamant about not actually sending a new request to the server if it already has a cached copy.

Comment: I already tried all these things.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `"?version=value"` to your request, like this:

```
<script src="myfile.js?v=1.0"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to handle this type of caching problem is versioning the resource file. 
In your case you can update file version like yourFile-1.2.js

and point the updated file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourFile-1.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution with the version, but the problem wasn't solved beacuse of my hosting provider.

In the last 24 hours I received an email about a new FREE cool feature for my website that was activated automatically: CloudFlare.

This cool feature started caching my website so today for the first time from that email I modified my web site and I got the problem.

Found the solution in the FAQ of my web hosting provider. I activated, in the new cool feature, the developer mode.

So now I can live happy :)

Again, thanks for your informations. Could be useful to me in the future!

P.S. This new COOOOOOOOOL feature was the result of a new partnership between Altervista (my hosting service provider) and CloudFlare.